# Wordpress Issue Create Sub Menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I just making sure that I'm creating the submenu on dashboard correctly.

I'm watching a tutorial on how to create a Setting API on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1UvKtGMm3A)

The problem is when every I hover on ALLB Option Sitting does pop up with the submenu.

Can anyone help with this quick issue having on WordPress, please explain with detail?

```
<?php

/*

    ====================
              Admin Page
    ====================

*/

function allb_admin_page() {
  //Generate A Legacy Left Behind Admin Page
  add_menu_page( ' ALLB Theme Options', 'ALLB Options', 'manage_options', 'a_legacy_left_behind', 'allb_theme_create_page', 'dashicons-admin-customizer', 110);
  //Generate A Legacy Left Behind Admin Sub Page
  add_submenu_page('allb_theme', 'ALLB Theme Options', 'Setting', 'manage_options', 'a_legacy_left_behind', 'allb_theme_settings_page');
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'allb_admin_page');

function allb_theme_create_page() {
  // genration of our admin page
}

function allb_theme_settings_page() {
  // genration of our admin page
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer..
**Just copy and past this code in your theme's functions.php file..**


Would you please try it once ?

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_menu_pages');
function my_menu_pages(){
    add_menu_page('My Page Title', 'My Menu Title', 'manage_options', 'my-menu', 'my_menu_output' );
    add_submenu_page('my-menu', 'Submenu Page Title', 'Whatever You Want', 'manage_options', 'my-menu' );
    add_submenu_page('my-menu', 'Submenu Page Title2', 'Whatever You Want2', 'manage_options', 'my-menu2' );
}
```

I hope its helpful for you..

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will solve your issue

```
function allb_admin_page() {
  //Generate A Legacy Left Behind Admin Page
  add_menu_page( 'ALLB Theme Options', 'ALLB Options', 'manage_options', 'a_legacy_left_behind', 'allb_theme_create_page');
  //Generate A Legacy Left Behind Admin Sub Page
  add_submenu_page('a_legacy_left_behind', 'ALLB Theme Options', 'Setting', 'manage_options', 'a_legacy_left_behind_sub', 'allb_theme_settings_page');
}
```